# Bit banging SPI

Tags: pi-2

1. I have to interface MCP3208 by bit banging. 
   Can't do it on SPi hardware as TFT is connected to it which uses both CS pins.
2. I was looking for SPI with bit banging examples.
   One I found is here, will try it & will see the resullts:
   https://github.com/raspberrypi-aa/raspb ... ng_test.py
3. I don't know how to set speed here or what's the speed here.
4. Any other source to use SPI by bit banging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to simulate SPI in code, instead of using hardware spi pins. Try to google that, I found something like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68827/manual-spi-interface-on-raspberry-pi)